# hibernate jpa table and view entities exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Hibernate - jpa - spring - java

I have a Entity for following table.

```
table1
------
id, field1, field2

@Entity
public class Table1Entity{

private UUID id;
private String field1;
private String field2;
}
```

i want to introduce field which will be calculated on run time using joins.
so i created a view on tabl1 adds a column calc_field

```
table1_v
--------
id, field1, field2, calc_field

@Entity
public class Table1VEntity extends Table1Entity{

private Integer calcField;

}
```

Question1. is it proper way to do it ?
Question2. when i try to get list of records from Table1Entity it throws exception with

```
"DTYPE" invalid identifier InvalidDataAccessResoureUseageException nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException could not extract ResultSet
```

Comment: The inheritance chosen (by default) requires a discriminator, and a single table ... not multiple tables. You evidently haven't defined one ...

Comment: can you help what should be discriminator here ?

Comment: help? you seem to want multiple tables, and I advised you that the default is a single table. So decide if you are going for multiple tables or a single table ... as per the JPA spec http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/mapping.html#inheritance

Comment: thanks for the link. i checked discriminator is attached on column name and value but in my case i don' have a column in table1 instead i want to place discriminator on if column exist or not. any advise ?

Comment: A discriminator is a COLUMN. The contents of the COLUMN. It is not the column not existing. As already said, UNLESS you set the inheritance it expects 1 table, not 1 table and 1 view.

Comment: You can use the same table for both persisted and calculated fields...use `@Postload` jpa annotation to calculate your field...btw I didn't see the `@Id` for the  entity identifier!